# Open .exe application from .NET console application

Tags: c#, console-application, system.diagnostics

If I try to open Notepad from a .NET console application it works fine.
I'm doing it as follows:

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
    }
};

p.Start();
```

When I try to open the application I actually want to open, nothing happens. If I open that application by hand I see a Java process being created, which means it's a Java application packaged as an exe file.

Any ideas on how to open Java exe apps through .NET?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hm... there shouldn't be much of a difference there. Have you tried adjusting the working directory? Maybe there's some unzipping going on.

Comment: In the debugger, explore the properties of the `p` after this line `p.Start();`. The process could have started and immediately terminated. In this case you would see the exit code property. See if this helps you.

Comment: That solved it Thorsten. I had to set the working directory as the root folder where the application lives. Can you add an answer so I can accept it? Thanks ;)

Comment: @Dante: Copied my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be much of a difference between a regular EXE and an "exified" Java application. Have you tried adjusting the working directory? Maybe there's some unzipping going on.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you had an application named "HelloWorld".  Then from a command prompt (and from your code) you would launch it with:

```
java HelloWorld
```

Now this would assume that `java` is in your path.  Which is a bad assumption.  So you would be better off either having logic to populate the path to `java`, or to hardcode it.

I don't ever recommend hardcoding a path if you plan to pass this software around.  It's never a sure thing...

Comment: It's an .exe application, not a jar or something. I can open it as any other app (double click icon, calling it from a command prompt, ...), the only place this doesn't work is when called from .NET.